# Mobile Connect SMS - Mobile Filtered List

Tags: mobileconnect, contactbuilder

I am trying to send SMS with Mobile Connect.

- I have the data extension in Contact Builder, in the Mobile Connect attribute group.
- I use this data extension to create a Mobile Filtered List applying the filters I want within the Mobile Connect interface
- Output is a Mobile Filtered List that include subscribers I want BUT that has predefined column names (see screenshot), which apparenlty I cannot edit anywhere. This of course prevent me to import all the data extension attributes I would like to have in the Mobile Filtered List.

Question: where can I edit the Mobile Filtered List attributes (or column names)?

My overall goal is to send SMS through Automation Studio and populate the SMS text with AMP script and DE attributes.

Thanks. I offer beers (in Berlin) to the one who solve this one. F.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use Data designer to alter the attribute list.

Comment: Hi Kevin. Thanks for your comment. I am trying to figure but did not succeed yet. Lets start from scratch. 

I have a csv in FTP and I would like to create a Mobile Connect List of conacts with all the attributes I have in the csv. Please not the csv is a list of bookings and I would like to shoot SMS based on booking status.

Thanks again for your help. F.